# How do I notate the group created by composition of functions?

Tags: notation, function-and-relation-composition

How do I notate the set or group created by iterated composition of functions?  Is there a convention?

In particular I have a function $f(x)$ and I want to notate the following set:

$F=\{f^n(x):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

where $f^2(x)=f(f(x))$ etc.

Is there a convention?  I want to write:

$F=f^{\mathbb{N}}(x)$ ?

which I'm sure is clear and everybody would understand, but when I invent notation, people get cross (although they always seem to understand).  So I thought I better ask first.

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard notation for this. I'd just define $F:=\{f^n(x) : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (specifying that the exponent relates to composition) and then use $F$.

Comment: In general, this will not be a group

Comment: I sometimes write $f^{\circ k}(x)$ and using $\circ$ like $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$. I'm not aware of any standard notation either. The reason I don't just use $f^k(x)$ is that many people for example in high school learn to write $\sin^k(x) = \sin(x)^k$ and may therefore guess that $f^k(x) = f(x)^k$.

Comment: Yes it won't be a group since many functions are not invertible and a group demands each element has an inverse. If you restrict the elements to be invertible functions, then you may get a group.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you mean $\{f^n(x)|n\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq X$ or $\{f^n|n\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq \mathrm{End}(X)$. This suggests your notation isn't sufficiently clear.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The group operation is given by $f^a(x)\cdot f^b(x)=f^{a+b}(x)$ then I think it's a group is it not?  I'm not sure if you missed this, or if I missed something you're seeing!

Comment: @RobertFrost All groups elements $a$ must have inverses $a^{-1}$ to all their elements which are so that $aa^{-1} = a^{-1}a = e$ where $e$ is some identity element. The most reasonable identity element would be $f(x)=x$. So if $f^k$ is an element also $f^{-k}$ must exist.

Comment: @mathreadler agreed.  $f^a(x)\cdot f^b(x)=f^{a+b}(x)$ implies what you say, since $f^0(x)=x$

Comment: I don't think you fully understand. Take $f_c: X \rightarrow X: x \mapsto c$ where $c$ is a constant. What is the inverse function?

Comment: @Math_QED ok i get it. Although the example above is not necessarily a counterexample $f^{-1}(x)=c$ and this requires $X=\{c\}$.  But I know what you mean.

Comment: Yes $X$ mustn't be a singleton. Well noticed!

Comment: @Math_QED I think a more general rule is that for function composition of $f$ to be a group operation on $X$ requires that $f$ totally orders the set (not necessarily antisymmetrically). e.g. $f$ can be cyclic in degree $p$ such that $f^{-np}(x)=x\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and we have a cyclic group with $\lvert X\rvert=p$ such as $f(x)=x+1$ and the set of integers modulo $p$.

Comment: Just make sure it satisfies the definition of a group and you will be ok.

Comment: @Math_QED haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not be a conventional notation, as others have commented, but there is a conventional terminology. Also, there is a conventional way to bring groups into the picture, although not in the way that you have notated.

The function $n \mapsto f^n$ is called an *action* of $\mathbb{N}$, and the set $\{f^n(x) \,|\, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is called the *orbit* of the point $x$ under this action.

I see you did not indicate the domain of the function $f$; if I bring the domain into the picture with notation $f:X \to X$, then the function $n \mapsto f^n$ is called an *action of $\mathbb{N}$ on $X$*.

So far, I haven't mentioned groups. I agree with the comments and answers that it is inappropriate to refer to $\{f^n(x) \,|\, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ as a group.

However, there is a way to bring group theory into the discussion.

First, let's assume that $f$ is a bijection. In that case $f$ is an element of the set of permutations of the set $X$, which I'll denote $Sym(X)$. The set $Sym(X)$ is a group under the operation of function composition: for all $f,g \in Sym(X)$ we have $f \circ g \in Sym(X)$; the associative law holds $(f \circ g) \circ h = f \circ (g \circ h)$; and because each element $f \in Sym(X)$ is a bijection, it has an inverse $f^{-1}$ satisfying the inverse law $f^{-1} \circ f = f \circ f^{-1} = \text{Id}_X$.

So we have $f \in Sym(X)$.

Second, let's define the function $\mathcal{A} : \mathbb{Z} \to Sym(X)$ by the formula
$$\mathcal{A}(n) = f^n
$$
Then we can easily derive the formula $f^n \circ f^m = f^{n+m}$. In other words, $\mathcal{A}$ is a homomorphism from the group $\mathbb{Z}$ to the group $Sym(X)$. The image of this homomorphism is the subset
$$\{f^n \,|\, n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset Sym(X)
$$
And now we can bring in a standard result from group theory, which says that the image of every homomorphism from one group to a second group is a subgroup of the second group.

In conclusion, as long as $f$ is assumed to be a bijection, it follows that the set $\{f^n \,|\, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ does indeed form a group under the operation of composition.

Note well, however, that this does *not* mean that the set $\{f^n(x) \,|\, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a group, nor $\{f^n(x) \,|\, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ as originally asked. Those sets are more properly called orbits of the action (of $\mathbb{Z}$ or of $\mathbb{N}$, respectively).

Comment: Thanks Lee for such a thorough answer. In the problem I'm working on I start with $f(x)$ and some initial starting value $x$ and the task is to find the range of $f^n(x)$ for all possible $n$. So the range begins not defined but once worked out it will be the group's set and composition of $f$ over $x$ will be the group's operation. This seems to run counter to your definition in which the set (domain / range) must be defined first. I think what you imply is to first define a possibly wider domain & range and then find the subgroup of that which is the image of the homomorphism.

Comment: When you say the set $\{f^n(x) \,|\, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is not a group, this seems to be a matter of convention rather than rigour since it has all the group properties and its elements $\{f^0, f^1, f^2, \ldots\}$ are bound by the group rules.

Comment: It sounds, perhaps, that my use of the word "conventional" may differ from yours, so I may have misinterpreted your request for a "convention". What I mean is that the terminology and notation in my answer is a very widely used convention in mathematics, wherever the concept of a group action is applied. And your question fits quite nicely into this convention, because the homomorphism $\mathcal{A} : \mathbb{Z} \to Sym(X)$ described in my example is a very important and common example of a group action.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't criticising, I was checking if I understand correctly. I've learned a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $F := \{f^n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, you will not have a group, as not all functions are bijections, and therefore they are not invertible.

Note that you should specify what domain and codomain $f$ must have so we can know whether it makes sense to consider function composition. As it stands there, I assume domain and codomain are the same, otherwise it would be impossible to iterate function composition.

Considering your notation: I would just leave it as I did in the first sentence of this answer. This will usually be well understood, certainly if you add context where you explain that you use function composition..

A small remark:

If we consider the set $\{f: X\rightarrow X | f$ bijective$\}$, we do have a group, and this group is usually denoted as $Sym(X)$. Or if $X = \{1,2, \dots, n\}$, we also write $S_n$.

Another small remark:

$f(x)$ is not a function, it is a function $f$ that is applied to an element $x$ in the domain.

Comment: Thanks also for $f(x)$ is not a function... good to know.

Comment: My only dissatisfaction with this answer is in your example there are many $f$ and sets $X$ for which $f$ doesn't **define** the group.  For example  $X=\mathbb{Z}$ and say $f(x)=x+1$ if $x$ is odd and $x-1$ if $x$ is even then we have a bijective function, a domain and codomain of $X=\mathbb{Z}$ which doesn't define $X$ whereas $f(x)=x+1$ does.

Comment: What do you mean with $f(x) = x+1$ defines $X = \mathbb{Z}$. If you can be a bit clearer, I can edit my answer so your questions are solved.

Comment: I *think* what I mean is that all you need is any unit $x$ on which $f(f^{n}(x))$ is bijective $\forall f^n(x)$ and a group is defined having unit $x$ and its set $X$ can be derived from that definition. But I guess your insistence that the domain and range of $X$ is defined has the same effect.